# Easy way to get to "interesting" tab?

Tags: support, feature-request

When I type stackoverflow.com in the URL bar of my browser, I arrive at a tab with interesting questions, called "interesting".

I can't find any handy link to this tab: once I leave it, by clicking on a question, I seem to have to do "back" enough times to get back, or type in the URL bar again (or I could have a bookmark, of course).

Shouldn't there be a button/easy way to get there?  Am I missing it?

Comment: Did you tried clicking the Stack Overflow logo?

Comment: Dang, that's it.  Hardly obvious though eh?   "Click on the logo to get the most interesting question tab" ... not sure about that logic at all!

Comment: Well that takes you to the home page, where one of the tabs is Interesting.

Comment: I guess the obvious followup question is "why isn't Interesting one of the tabs that you get when you click on Questions"?

Comment: I'm in the A/B testing group for the new navigation @GreenAsJade

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Click on the logo]

Comment: cool!! what program do you use to record this?

Comment: @fedorqui https://screentogif.codeplex.com/ but there are more around...